# openssl-devel-1.1.0f package for CentOS 7

Tags: openssl, centos7

Does anyone knows how to get openssl-devel-1.1.0f package for Centos 7?

I found this https://pkgs.org/download/openssl-devel however it seems there is no openssl-devel-1.1.0f package available for CentOS.

Is there a way to build that package for CentOS?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: [Noloader | Build-Scripts](https://github.com/noloader/Build-Scripts) might help. They are usually used for older machines, like CentOS 5. The script is hard-wired for OpenSSL 1.0.2, and you will need to change the tarball name to get 1.1.0. Keep in mind many packages that link against OpenSSL cannot handle 1.1.0, so it will be of limited usefulness (speaking from experience).